# install magento multi source Inventory after magento234 has been installed

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multi-source-inventory

I installed magento 234 and I have been using it . recently I tried to install a warehouse app and noticed it was giving me errors,

It specifically asked for
magento/module-inventory
magento/module-inventory-source-selection

I was told that the magento 234 did not come with inventory module in it.
How do i get this done? i have referred to other sites and I have been told to reinstall from scratch.

I need a way out
Urgent!

Answer (score 0):

I have found it. It can be independently uploaded via composer

https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki/MSI-Release-Notes-and-Installation